# Power bi and bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi

I faced the problem with power bi connecting to Google Bigquery.
it used to work fine but since last week power Bi cannot connect to gbq.
google authorization window shows an error that says: 
"entrance to google account temporary blocked for this app.
you cannot log in the app using this google account as this app hasn't been verified yet"

Is anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: It sounds as through the PowerBI app itself is having to re-auh with Google, have you tried raising this with them directly?

Comment: for now, we use free version of both services so techsupport is not avalible for us :)

Comment: This looks like the issue described [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7455163?authuser=1&p=app_notverified&authuser=1&visit_id=1-636630845630894004-19904233&rd=1) (I assumed you are the user asking this same question in [this thread](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Integrations-with-Files-and/Google-Bigquerry-error/m-p/430259)). Isn't there an **Advanced** button underneath the message?

Comment: Also, do you use the [BigQuery connector](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-august-2017-feature-summary/#GoogleBigQuery)? I am not familiar with power bi, but while setting up you must have identified with some google account. Can you run queries directly in BigQuery when logged in with this account?

Comment: yep, this post is mine :) no, there're no any links/buttons in this window. seems gbq just blocked power bi..... also yes, i can run queries in gbq in the same account and i use gbq native connector in power bi